# Back button with Swift UI

Tags: swiftui

I want to dismiss the popup when the back button is pressed. This is the code:

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
          [SOME STUFF HERE]
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Creatives Screen", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarItems(leading:
          Button(action: {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            print("Button pressed")
          }) {
            HStack {
              Image(systemName: "arrow.left.circle")
              Text("Back")
            }
          }
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The popup originates here:

[SOME STUFF]

```
Section {
          Button("Reset Form") {
            resetForm()
          }
          Button("Request Data") {
            getCreatives()
          }
          
        }
      }
      .navigationBarTitle("Dummy page", displayMode: .inline)
      .sheet(isPresented: .constant(!creatives.isEmpty)) {
        Screen(creatives: self.screen)
      }
    }
  }
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Are you supporting a low version of swiftui? You are using every deprecated method. But it is impossible to help since we dont know where you popup comes from

Comment: I use Swift version 5.7.2

Comment: Not Swift, SwiftUI it is more related to the OS version, the only justification for using all of these old methods is if you are supporting iOS 13, which very few developers do at this point. `.toolbar`, `navigationTitle` and `navigationBarTitleDisplayMode` were introduced in iOS 14, `@Environment(\.dismiss)` was introduced in iOS 15 and `NavigationStack` was introduced in iOS 16.

Comment: I am using iOS 14

Comment: You should adopt `toolbar` then but that will likely not fix your issue, we still dont know where the popup originates

Comment: Added the origin of the popup

Comment: Never use `.constant` outside of `Previews` use a `Binding`

Answer (score 0):

** works on ios 17**

```
var body: some View {

 @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    NavigationView {
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Creatives Screen", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        
        .toolbar{
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                Button(action: {
                    dismiss()
            print("Button pressed")
          }) {
            HStack {
              Image(systemName: "arrow.left.circle")
              Text("Back")
            }
          }
        
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).